# Missing lines in a table filtered by date

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

So I have a filter by date for a dataset. And it happens that for certain dates I have more than 1 line of data.
[image]

But i know for a fact there are missing lines so The problem is that for some reason it doesn't output the whole data lines and I am sure the date format is correct cause i am getting back like 15% of the data. Here are few images that might help to understand.

[image]

Comment: If you want consecutive dates then you either need an auto calendar or a date dimension. Good resources from Radacad are https://radacad.com/create-a-date-dimension-in-power-bi-in-4-steps-step-1-calendar-columns and https://radacad.com/do-you-need-a-date-dimension

Comment: I think that cannot be done because even when I am calling this "date", as you can see the format is different to a proper date in power bi (MM/DD/YYYY)). So this is (YYYY-MM-DD) and I had to treat it like a text column...

Comment: Hard to see what you are doing between the screenshots (vs text) and the blanked out information. But, in general, you should be treating dates as dates and not as text strings. Makes life much easier in the long run.